# Vert.x: simplest server with 1000 rps

Tags: java, vert.x, reactor, high-load

Suppose you need to write a server with 1000 rps. The load may grow in the future. Server is serving only one kind of request - `getGender(name)` which accept a name, and return `Male`/`Female`. Determinition of sex is simplest operation which requires single index lookup, where index is an in-memory data structure.

If understand it right - you create single `ServerVerticle`, and run `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` worker verticles to which delegate the job (see code below).

***Questions:***

1. *Is this the best scheme for the task of 1000 rps?*
2. *What will happen on request peak when there will be unsufficient 15 workers?* Suppose one worker can handle 100 rps. You have 15 workers. But at peak time you have 3000 rps.

   - Suppose `NetServer` can handle 3000 rps, but workers stuck to handle them. *Have Vert.x got any queue to keep waiting requests? How to do that? If it has - what happens on worker fail?*
   - Suppose `NetServer` can't handle 3000 rps - just run few instances of a server. *No pitfalls, right?*
3. *Is TCP the better choice for the task?*
4. Vert.x is multi-reactor, which like Node runs it event-loop.
   *`ServerVerticle` is run in the same thread as event-loop, right?*
5. *If you have 16 cores, 1 core is dedicated for event-loop, so Vert.x will run 15 GenderVerticles, right?* No more thereads?

***ServerVerticle.java***

```
public class ServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Vertx> runner = vertx -> vertx.deployVerticle("ServerVerticle", new DeploymentOptions());
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        runner.accept(vertx);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        NetServerOptions options = new NetServerOptions();
        NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer(options);
        server.connectHandler(socket -> {
            socket.handler(buffer -> {
                vertx.eventBus.send("get.gender", buffer, res -> socket.write(res.toString()));
            });
        });
        server.listen(1234, "localhost");

        //Deploy worker verticles
        DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
            .setInstances(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
            .setWorker(true);
       vertx.deployVerticle("GenderServiceVerticle", deploymentOptions);
    } 
}
```

***GenderVerticle.java***

```
public class GenderVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        vertx.eventBus().consumer("get.gender", message -> {
            String gender = singleIndexLookup(message);
            message.reply(gender);
        });
    }

    singleIndexLookup() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several questions here and some misconceptions about vert.x. Once you implement your code using `Verticle`s you do not need to implement your own `main` method, since under the wood what the internal `main` method will do it to make sure you can have the full capacity of your CPU power and you do not need to scale it yourself with:

```
//Deploy worker verticles
DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
  .setInstances(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

You should read the following section of the [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vert_x_launcher).

Second you are referring to your `GenderVerticle` as a **worker** because it will do some operation for you. Note that in `vertx`, **worker** means that it should be executed on a dedicated thread pool since it could happen that the code in that verticle will perform some blocking IO.

Using the **worker** mode will introduce a performance penalty since you loose the benefits of asynchronous IO and your requests need to queue for a thread from the pool.

Since your example explains that all your code does is a in memory look-up I assume it is CPU bounded and not IO bound which means you should avoid deploying it as a worker.

Going back to your example, you have 1 verticle that handles all the HTTP trafic and a second one that processes it. For top performance you might want to have just 1 verticle since there are less hops but this solutions does not scale horizontally (the reason of your question) how do I handle 3000rps assuming one node can only do 1000rps.

Now you're already going on the right path, you split http handling from business handling, it has a little penalty but if you know that 1 node can process 1000rps and you must at least handle 3000rps all you need to do is deploy the `GenderVerticle` on 3 extra machines.

Once you do this and enable clustering, and you do this by adding the dependency (e.g: hazelcast):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And by starting your application with the flag `--cluster`. You will have a cluster of 4 machines where the requests will be load balanced in a round robin fashion to each of the `GenderVerticles`.

Since the HTTP code is highly optimized by netty you will probably not need more than one server, if that is not the case, one option you can do it to add a traffic load balancer in front of your servers and again deploy another `ServerVerticle` in another machine in your cluster, now the traffic load balancer will load balance the HTTP traffic between the 2 servers which will round robin to the `GenderVerticles`.

So I guess you start to see the pattern that once your monitoring tells you your CPU/NetworkIO is being maxed out you add more machines to the cluster.

Comment: thank you for so full disclosure! But can you explain how would I benefit from multithreading/multicore if I had only one ServerVerticle/GenderVerticle per machine? How Vert.x will parallelize request processing on single machine if it will have only one verticle? Sorry, haven't find through the link http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vert_x_launcher answer why I don't need main method and manuall CPU match. This code `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is also taken from the same documentation

Comment: in other words clustering is a solution, but how to get benefit from all 16 cores of single machine with Vert.x?

Comment: Perhaps the documentation is not clear, but the default behavior of the default launcher is that it will always spawn one event loop per CPU core. So in your case with 16 cores you will have 16 event loops. This will maximize your CPU usage to the maximum. The answer is here: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor but it is not clear that it is provided out of the box if you use the default launcher.

Comment: my bad, that's said clear in docs. Pls one more question - if I have `ServerVerticle` and `GenderVerticle` as standard workers, Vert.x by default will deploy them in single  instance. So there will be one instance of `GenderVerticle` and 16 event loops, right? How the concurrency will be done than??

Comment: Say that your instance does impose some sort of locking (say somewhere there is a synchronized block) then you might not be able to use the full capacity of the event loops, in that case you might tune your performance using the command line argument `--instances N` which will spawn `N` instances of your Verticles

Comment: @pauloLopes when i implement main method, i cannot get metric via worker, do u know reason ?